# Filtering only on DataGridView items

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter

```
dv.RowFilter = String.Format("NAME like '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text)
gridunpaid.DataSource = dv
```

i used this code above to filter and it is working fine.

here is what i want. only in the Data Grid View item will filter not on database is this possible?

Comment: it is not at all clear what you are asking

Comment: i want to filter without using the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `DataGridView` without changing `DataSource` using this code:

```
Ctype(gridunpaid.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("NAME like '%{0}%'", txtsearch.Text)
```

Comment: i am getting this error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'."

Comment: so use Ctype(gridunpaid.DataSource, DataView).RowFilter